# unable to echo out the link

Tags: php, html

I am unable to `echo` out this link on to my page i get no errors or whatsoever  just unable to `echo` out this part i do not understand what i am doing wrong.

`

```
    $friend_query = ("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one ='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'");

    while ($run_friend = mysql_fetch_array($friend_query))
    {
        $user_one = $run_friend['user_one'];
        $user_two = $run_friend['user_two'];

            if ($user_one == $my_id)
            {
                $user = $user_two;
            }else
                {
                    $user = $user_one;
                }
            $username = getuser ($user, 'username');
                echo "<a href='profile.php?user=$user' class='box' style='display:block'>$username</a>";

    }


?>`
```

all the variables are defined i believe there is something wrong with this line only, since all others work fine.
Thanking in advance for the help

p.s do not vote down i am just a beginner :)

Comment: `echo "<a href='profile.php?user=".$user."' class='box' style='display:block'>". $username ."</a>";`

Comment: try this echo "<a href=profile.php?user=".$user."class=box style=display:block>".$username."</a>";

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that line of code.

Comment: Being a beginner will not "protect" you from down votes, down votes has nothing to do with the level of your coding but the quality of your question.

Comment: @aldrin27 it doesn't work

Comment: Being a beginner won't save you from getting downvotes, since even beginners can reach the tour page.

Comment: do you get any error messages?

Comment: So what does the html source look like? Note that the variables in your string can invalidate the html if they are not properly encoded.

Comment: nope no error message

Comment: Hold on i will post my whole code

Comment: is there a conditional statement prior to this line, because there's nothing wrong with what you've got unless `$user` or `$username` aren't strings or numbers

Comment: i have edited my code please have a look now

Comment: does your while loop ever run? easy way to check is put `print_r($run_friend);exit;` on the first line after the while loop opens

Comment: You need to do some basic trouble-shooting, are you even getting any results, are you not sql-injecting yourself, etc.

Comment: @iam-decoder nothing is displayed when i tried it

Comment: @jake123 then you're not retrieving anything from the database, there might not be any `user_one`s or `user_two`s that match `$my_id`

Comment: okay i will check on that and get back to you

Comment: @iam-decoder Everything seems okay i even spelled everything correct in my database also in my php 
i dont seem to get around this trouble

Comment: before the first line in your example, do `var_dump($my_id);exit;`

Comment: @iam-decoder `string(1) "1"` I get this out put

Comment: i am using `phpMyAdmin 3.5.8 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have received an error, but you may have suppressed them without realizing it. [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) needs a query [`resource`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) in order to run, you're just passing in a string, change the first line of your example to:

```
$friend_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one ='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'");
```

Answer (score 3):

The line is perfectly valid. Try removing the class and style, since it's very possible that the line cannot be seen because of some styling glitch. Work on that.

Comment: i have removed all styling still no improvement

Answer (score 2):

You are not executing the query...

Use this `mysql_query` before the actual query.

```
$friend_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_one, user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one ='$my_id' OR user_two='$my_id'");
```

Keep the rest of the code. That should do the job.

ADDON: I would advice to use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql as it is deprecated.